# Mongodb Query greater than value in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Trying to query mongo to return documents that contain a value within an array that is greater than a certain value.  Here is my confusion...

```
> db.homes.findOne({},{'listing.location.latitude': 1})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("545fd08f37e6134b5796a085"),
    "listing" : {
        "location" : [
            {
                "latitude" : [
                    "38.68431"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Makes sense, just returns the field that I want. However when I query on this field, it fails:

```
> db.homes.findOne({'listing.location.latitude': {$gt: 0}})
null
```

I believe it has to do with the arrays in the structure but I do not know how to query it differently within an array.  What am I doing wrong?  The goal will be to transfer this query to mongoose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is your actual data, you are keeping latitude as String `"38.68431"`. You need to persist it as float to run your query properly.

Comment: Yea sadly I realized this minutes after I posted this. Was banging me head for a while and it just took me posting it to realize... Thanks